# Как добавить строку в массив?

Tags: php

Добавляю в массив `$arr[]` инфу с БД

```
$num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($num != '0'){
        for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
            $arr[] = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        }
    }else{
        $arr = 'nodata';
    }

    return $arr;
```

плюс ко всему, мне нужно значение `$num`, это число от 1-999, как его правильно добавить в массив `$arr` с ключом `num`?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, какую строку и где именно вы хотите добавить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr['num'] = $num;
```

Полагаю об этом речь.